# Отправка писем php-скриптом через SMTP

Tags: email, php, smtp

Товарищи гуру бек-энда, к вам вопрос.
Битый час бьюсь с SMTP-отправкой писем с сайта. Был у меня рабочий скрипт, сейчас вроде работает, но письма отправляет очень редко, раз в 10 минут, если отправляешь чаще - просто ничего не приходит.

gmail вообще не хочет, гад, работать.
ukr.net отправляет, но не принимает.
Яндекс принимает, но не отправляет.

Может ли мой хостер принять меня за спамера и глушить поток?
Если есть 100% рабочий PHP-скрипт отправки почты через SMTP c SSL - буду благодарен, если поделитесь.

Comment: >может ли мой хостер принять меня за спамера и глушить поток?

Не исключено, да и для начала нужно выяснить причину вопроса, для его дальнейшего решения.

Comment: следите еще за тем, что скину ниже, может кто то подскажет, мне нужен именно гугл, но можете попробовать мой скрипт для других почтовников

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/508078/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-smtp

Answer (score 1):

Надеюсь, на вашем хостинге есть пхп без ограничений, тогда можно воспользоваться штатным sendmail-ом через сокеты:

```
$from = 'from@email.com';   
$subject ='[some] test';  
$to = 'to@email.com';  
$message = 'some text message';

        $connect = fsockopen ('127.0.0.1', 25, $errno, $errstr, 30);
        if(!$connect){
            echo json_encode($errno);
        } else {
            fputs($connect, "HELO localhost\r\n");
            fputs($connect, "MAIL FROM: $from\n");
            fputs($connect, "RCPT TO: to@email.com\n"); // если нужно н-колько адресатов, то нужно сделать н-колько таких строк, по одному адресу
            fputs($connect, "DATA\r\n");                              
            fputs($connect, "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
            fputs($connect, "MIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n");
            fputs($connect, "To: $to\r\n");                                
            fputs($connect, "Subject: =?utf-8?b?".base64_encode($subject)."?=\r\n");  
            fputs($connect, $message." \r\n");
            fputs($connect, ".\r\n");
            fputs($connect, "RSET\r\n"); 
        }
        fclose($connect);
```

Comment:     echo json_encode("mailerror");

что?

Comment: проблемы?..

Comment: echo "$errstr ($errno)"; Не?

Comment: Можно и так. Задача этой ветки ифа - просто дать понять юзеру, есть ли у него доступ к сендмайлу.

Comment: в json-то зачем строку пихать?