# Не могу отправить письмо через SMTP

Tags: php, smtp, gmail

Написал модуль для отправки писем через gmail на SMTP. Пол года работал нормально, проблем не было. Чего то перестал работать, возвращает ошибку 501

```
Ошибка: 5.5.4 HELO/EHLO argument ssl://smtp.gmail.com invalid, closing connection. e25sm23107227wmi.21 - gsmtp вместо 250
62
```

Подскажите, что могло случится, что перестало все работать?

Подробнее: 
   Кусок текста для отправки:

```
$sendMail = new sendMail("******@gmail.com", "******", 465, "ssl://smtp.gmail.com", "utf-8", "Error Reporting");
$sendMail->From('Error Reporting');
$sendMail->To('******@gmail.com');
$sendMail->Subject('Error Reporting');
$message = 'test test test';
```

сам клас отправки:

```
<?php

class sendMail{

    private $username = false;
    private $password = false;
    private $port = false;
    private $host = false;
    private $charset = false;
    private $from = false;
    private $debug = false;

    private $_from = '';
    private $_to = '';
    private $_subject = '';
    private $_send = '';
    private $_message = '';

    public function __construct($username, $password, $port, $host, $charset, $from) {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->port = $port;
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->charset = $charset;
        $this->from = $from;
        $this->debug = true;
    }

    public function From($name){
        $this->_from = "From: " . '=?utf-8?B?'.base64_encode($name).'?=' . " <" . $this->username . ">";
    }

    public function To($email){
        $this->_to = $email;
    }

    public function Subject($subject){
        $this->_subject = $subject;
    }

    public function Message($message){
        $this->_message = $message;
    }

    public function smtpmail(){
        $this->_send .= "Date: ".date("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " UT\r\n";
        $this->_send .= "Subject: =?" . $this->charset .'?B?' . base64_encode($this->_subject) . "=?=\r\n";
        $this->_send .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset="' . $this->charset .'"' . "\r\n";
        $this->_send .= $this->_from."\r\n";
        $this->_send .= "To: '" . $this->_to . "'<" . $this->_to . ">"."\r\n";
        $this->_send .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n\r\n";
        $this->_send .= $this->_message."\r\n";

        if( !$socket = fsockopen($this->host, $this->port, $errno, $errstr, 30) ) {
            if ($this->debug) echo $errno."&lt;br&gt;".$errstr;
            return false;
        }

        if (!$this->server_parse($socket, "220", __LINE__)) return false;

        fputs($socket, "EHLO " . $this->host . "\r\n");
        if (!$this->server_parse($socket, "250", __LINE__)) {
            if ($this->debug) echo '<p>Не могу отправить HELO!</p>';
            fclose($socket);
            return false;
        }
        fputs($socket, "AUTH LOGIN\r\n");
        if (!$this->server_parse($socket, "334", __LINE__)) {
            if ($this->debug) echo '<center><p>Не могу найти ответ на запрос авторизаци.</p></center>';
            fclose($socket);
            return false;
        }
        fputs($socket, base64_encode($this->username) . "\r\n");
        if (!$this->server_parse($socket, "334", __LINE__)) {
            if ($this->debug) echo '<center><p>Логин авторизации не был принят сервером!</p></center>';
            fclose($socket);
            return false;
        }
        fputs($socket, base64_encode($this->password) . "\r\n");
        if (!$this->server_parse($socket, "235", __LINE__)) {
            if ($this->debug) echo '<center><p>Пароль не был принят сервером как верный! Ошибка авторизации!</p></center>';
            fclose($socket);
            return false;
        }
        fputs($socket, "MAIL FROM: <".$this->username.">\r\n");
        if (!$this->server_parse($socket, "250", __LINE__)) {
            if ($this->debug) echo '<center><p>Не могу отправить комманду MAIL FROM: </p></center>';
            fclose($socket);
            return false;
        }
        fputs($socket, "RCPT TO: <" . $this->_to . ">\r\n");

        if (!$this->server_parse($socket, "250", __LINE__)) {
            if ($this->debug) echo '<center><p>Не могу отправить комманду RCPT TO: </p></center>';
            fclose($socket);
            return false;
        }
        fputs($socket, "DATA\r\n");

        if (!$this->server_parse($socket, "354", __LINE__)) {
            if ($this->debug) echo '<center><p>Не могу отправить комманду DATA</p></center>';
            fclose($socket);
            return false;
        }
        fputs($socket, $this->_send ."\r\n.\r\n");

        if (!$this->server_parse($socket, "250", __LINE__)) {
            if ($this->debug) echo '<center><p>Не смог отправить тело письма. Письмо не было отправленно!</p></center>';
            fclose($socket);
            return false;
        }
        fputs($socket, "QUIT\r\n");
        fclose($socket);
        return TRUE;
    }

    private function server_parse($socket, $response, $line = __LINE__) {
        while (@substr($server_response, 3, 1) != ' ') {
            if (!($server_response = fgets($socket, 256))) {
                if ($this->debug) echo "<p>Problems sending mail!</p>$response<br>$line<br>";
                return false;
            }
        }
        if (substr($server_response, 0, 3) != $response) {
            if ($this->debug) echo "<p>Problems sending mail!</p>$server_response вместо $response<br>$line<br>";
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Столкнулся с такой же проблемой. Проверь что у тебя посылается в EHLO.
С EHLO smtp.gmail.com должно работать.

Comment: скинул весь свой код,  EHLO. С EHLO smtp.gmail.com не работает, может я что то не понял, обьясните пожайлуста

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google недавно внесла изменение в условия доставки сообщений. 
Подключение отклоняется, если аргументы HELO/EHLO не указаны или являются недопустимыми. Если данные сервера недействительны (например доменное имя), сообщение отклоняется или возвращается.

[Справочная статья](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6386757)